# Set default append location?

Tags: customization, blend-files

I made a customized startup.blend with nodegroups and other assets I use a lot by appending the appropriate data blocks from other files, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>.

However, now when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to append in a new file, the file browser opens in the last blendfile I appended from when I set up my default .blend.

I would like it to not open in any blendfile, just in the default directory (By default I mean the one which appears when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> in a new file).

Is there a way to explicitly define what directory should be opened when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>?

I tried pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, navigating to the directory I would like to default, and pressing *Append*, but I get the error `Not a Library`, obviously because I have not selected a blendfile.  Even if I save the default .blend after doing this, it will not overwrite the previously saved default location for appending.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Using a favourite folder takes "only" one more click. Could be a workaround for you.

Comment: @Gunslinger I guess that is what I will do if there is no way around, but it is still quite annoying..

Comment: See discussion on blender bug tracker: https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=498&aid=31314&group_id=9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to let it start in a certain directory from script:
`bpy.ops.wm.link_append('INVOKE_AREA', directory="C:\\tmp")`

Hence, it's possible to bind a key combination for that as well. You can simply edit the existing Shift+F1 binding:

[image: Set default path for link/append operator]

Set search type to *Key-Binding*, search for "Shift F1", expand the entry and pick a directory.

Comment: Note that 2.68a has a bug where selecting any paths from the keymap editor can crash, This has been fixed and will be working in 2.69 (or any recent build).